# Where can I find the reference manual of bnfc?

Tags: reference-manual, bnfc

I cannot find a man page, for bnfc. On the home page of *bnfc* there aren't link pointing to a man page.

The only option that I know is **-m** for generating the make file; but this knowledge, I learned from the tutorial on the home page of *bnfc*.

What I am searching is an option to generate only the lexer file and the parser file. I don't need documentation files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get a list of option with the flag `-h`.

But in the current bnfc version (2.6) there is no option to prevent the generation of the latex file. If you don't wan't to compile the pdf, the easiest is to modify the Makefile.

The next release won't generate latex by default.